# Caching mechanism on ActionFilterAttribute of Actions not working on F5 or ctrl+R on Firefox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, browser-cache, actionfilterattribute

Hello I am using a caching mechanism on OnResultExecuting of the ActionFilterAttribute I have overridden in an application I am working. The mechanism works as expected but I have an issue with Firefox. 
In Chrome caching works as expected in all cases. 
In Firefox caching works on simple reload (If I refresh the page from the url or the menu) but doesn't work on F5 refresh or ctrl+R which is the refresh button of the browser. My guess is that I am missing a response header but I can't figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Firefox version: 56.0.1

Here is my filter implementation

```
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var httpContext = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext;

        var jsonResult = filterContext.Result as JsonResult;
        if (jsonResult != null)
        {
            if (jsonResult.Data == null) return;

            var dataSourceResult = jsonResult.Data as DataSourceResult;
            if (dataSourceResult != null ) // Kendo mvc DataSourceResult (For Datasource transport.Read)
            {
                if(dataSourceResult.Total == 0) return;
            }
            else // IEnumerable list of objects (For Datasource source.Read)
            {
                dynamic firstItem = (jsonResult.Data as IEnumerable<dynamic>).FirstOrDefault(); //System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(jsonResult.Data);    
                if (firstItem == null) return;
            }
        }

        httpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
        httpContext.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0, 0, _maxAgeSeconds));

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```